# Point.in.polygon function in sf package miscalculate the distribution of points

Tags: r, polygon, point-in-polygon, sf, spatstat

I am using point.in.polygon function in sf package to determine whether a set of data fall within a polygon or not.
Here is a snippet of the data and polygon visualization
[image]

As the figure shows, there must be at least one point fully lies in the polygon, however, the point.in.polygon function returns all zero, which means the function thinks all points are exterior to the polygon.

Where am I do wrong?

codes
`subDist <- point.in.polygon(CD8_Pts[,1], CD8_Pts[,2], sub_current_poly[,1], sub_current_poly[,2])`

Edit: The following link is the polygon coordinates.
https://livejohnshopkins-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hmi1_jh_edu/EeC-sUzqPZJFtoUzM-r5DQ4B_aIsLri4G29RAi47uO42zw?e=Gw2oHt

Comment: There;s no such function in `sf` or `spatstat` packages. Theres one in `sp` which I assume works when fed the correct data. So the assumption is that your data isnt i the right format. Without your data there;s no way we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I attached the polygon data to the OneDrive, and you can download using this link mentioned in the question. You can use any data to test the function. (FYI I am sure that point (15, 20) should lie in the polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polygon seems to be two copies of the same ring, exactly overlapping. Look at the first five points and then the first five after the half-way mark:

```
> polygons[1:5,]
           x      y n
288842 4.232 20.240 5
288851 4.232 20.248 5
288861 4.232 20.256 5
288871 4.224 20.264 5
288881 4.224 20.272 5
> polygons[(nrow(polygons)/2)+(1:5),]
           x      y n
288844 4.232 20.240 5
288853 4.232 20.248 5
288863 4.232 20.256 5
288873 4.224 20.264 5
288883 4.224 20.272 5
```

The point (15,20) isn't in the polygon defined by this double ring:

```
> point.in.polygon(15,20,polygons[,1], polygons[,2])
[1] 0
```

But if you take only the first half of your `polygon` object then it is:

```
> point.in.polygon(15,20,polygons[1:(nrow(polygons)/2),1], polygons[1:(nrow(polygons)/2),2])
[1] 1
>
```

I think this duplication of the ring is messing up the point-in-polygon algorithm which expects a well-defined single ring polygon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Perfectly solved my problem!